# AngularJS ui-grid - Filter text box - Increase height

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

In AngularJS ui-grid module,

How to increase the filter textbox height ? (eg. Name, Phone, etc filter fields)

Here is the source demo

http://plnkr.co/edit/8Ax2wNSYiJe6XiLGIP25?p=preview

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you want.

```
input.ui-grid-filter-input[type="text"] {
    height: 60px;
}
```

will produce [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/SWEjYBQrQXWNZ8oxyQXV?p=preview)